# Catel InitializeAsync is Not Called in ViewModel

Tags: mvvm, catel

I have an issue where every single view model that inherits from `Catel.MVVM.ViewModel` is never calling `InitializeAsync()`. What could I be missing that blocks this call?

I'm using Catel.MVVM v5.12.22.

Comment: Did you change the control type from UserControl to catel:UserControl in xaml?

Comment: @GeertvanHorrik that did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is to change the control type from `UserControl` to `catel:UserControl`.

```xml
<catel:UserControl xmlns:catel="http://schemas.catelproject.com">
```

Edit: you might want to include validation messages.

```xml
<catel:UserControl>
    <catel:InfoBarMessageControl>
        [XAML Goes Here]
    </catel:InfoBarMessageControl>
</catel:UserControl>
```